# Ruby method to make a string like 'Hello World' be like 'hello_world'

Tags: ruby

What is the Ruby method to make a string like `Hello World` be like `hello_world`.

Comment: 5 answers and none upvoted the question ts ts ts ts ts...

Comment: @coder_tim: Ja! not anymore! :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't need Rails helpers. You can do it in pure ruby.

```
'Hello World'.downcase.tr(' ', '_')
# => hello_world
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it with Rails methods, you can also do:

In Rails 4:

```
"Hello World".parameterize('_')
=> "hello_world"
```

Or (in Rails 5):

```
"Hello World".parameterize(separator: '_')
=> "hello_world"
```

I think that's what @DGM was thinking of.

Rails 4 references:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_support_core_extensions.html#parameterize
https://apidock.com/rails/String/parameterize

Rails 5 reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-parameterize

Comment: Works in Rails 3.2 also!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
'Hello World'.gsub(/( )/, '_').downcase!
```

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to the other answers:

```
'Hello World'.split.join('_').downcase
  => 'hello_world'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'Hello World'.sub(' ', '_').downcase!
=> 'hello_world'
```

Comment: Ey, it wasn't me who down-voted your question :) Don't down vote me just because some else down-voted you. I think the down-vote was because of the typo 'doawncase', because otherwise you code works.

Comment: You need to use `String#gsub` if you want to replace multiple spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all these ways do what you want without rails, but to answer the actual question, rails provides `underscore`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore

Comment: That converts transition from lower case to upper case into underscores, but does that convert spaces into underescores?

Comment: yes, plus a bit more, actually.  look at the source linked from it.

Comment: I looked at the source. It doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: hmm, you're right. well, then the question as stated is impossible to answer. ;)

Comment: I edited the question to reflect this; it's more useful as a general ruby question.

Answer (score 1):

"Hello World".downcase.split.join("_")

Comment: You can also use the Rails "underscore" method: "Hello World".tr(' ', '').underscore

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'Hello World'
str.downcase!.tr!(' ','_')
p str #=> hello_world
```

Answer (score 0):

"Hello World".gsub(" ","").underscore